# Powershell Import-CSV - compare with text file. speed optimalization?

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script which compares words from a text-file with a csv-column, and if the word in the column matches, the line is deleted.

My code works great, but it is very slow, due to saving and copying the csv file after every line. Is there a way improving this?

```
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($fc_file.Text)
    try {
        for() {
            $line = $reader.ReadLine()
            if ($line -eq $null) { break }
            if ($line -eq "") { break }
            # process the line
            $fc_suchfeld = $fc_ComboBox.Text
            $tempstorage = $scriptPath + "\temp\temp.csv"
            Import-Csv $tempfile -Delimiter $delimeter -Encoding $char | where {$_.$fc_suchfeld -notmatch [regex]::Escape($line)} | Export-Csv $tempstorage -Delimiter $delimeter -Encoding $char  -notypeinfo
            Remove-Item $tempfile 
            Rename-Item $tempstorage $tempfile_ext           
        }
    }
    finally {
        $reader.Close()
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So you re-read and re-parse the entire CSV file for each line of text. This is... brutal!

Comment: Where does your fc_ComboBox come from?